# Generic return types in java returns object

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I have a method that is intended to allow consumers of my SDK to pull objects out of an internal store.  These objects inherit from a base class that is a generic class.  The true type of the object is deterministic and known only to the consumer.  The setup looks like this:

```
public class MyBaseClass<T> {
    ...
}

public class TheBaseClassContainer {
    private Map<String, MyBaseClass> container;

    public <T extends MyBaseClass> T getOne(String id, Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(this.container.get(id));
    }
}
```

The idea being that consumers can simply specify the class they're expecting back and we'll handle the rest.  Unfortunately when I call this method like so:

```
TheBaseClassContainer container = ...;
MyBaseClassSubclass subclass = container.getOne("myId", MyBaseClassSubclass.class);
```

I get a compile failure saying that container.getOne is returning type MyBaseClass and the assignment is expecting an object of type MyBaseClassSubclass.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Give the exact error message. Note that `MyBaseClass` is generic. You should parameterize its use.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me mate:

```
    class MyBaseClass<T> {
}

class B extends  MyBaseClass<Integer>{}

class TheBaseClassContainer {
    private Map<String, MyBaseClass> container;

    public <T extends MyBaseClass> T getOne(String id, Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(this.container.get(id));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
    TheBaseClassContainer theBaseClassContainer = new TheBaseClassContainer();
    B asd = theBaseClassContainer.getOne("asd", B.class);
```

Compiles in Java 7.